# NextGEN Gallery - set lightbox image size

Tags: plugin-nextgen-gallery, lightbox

I use NextGEN gallery with lightbox effect. Is there any way how to set the lightboxed image to f. ex. to max width: 600px? Without resizing the source image? I have tried all of possible Lightbox Effect setting, but nothing has helped.

We use big pictures (+3000px width) because our users can download them through [NextGEN Download Gallery](http://shop.webaware.com.au/downloads/nextgen-download-gallery/) so we don't want to resize them. But if you click on image as a lightbox is loaded the big image which is really useless and pretty big so it takes time and data traffic.

I have read throught this topic but it didn't worked for me:

- [auto-resize-gallery-based-on-browser-size-or-scrn-resolution](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/auto-resize-gallery-based-on-browser-size-or-scrn-resolution)
- [nextgen-problem-resize-images-automatically-in-screen-resolution-function](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/nextgen-problem-resize-images-automatically-in-screen-resolution-function)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally founded the solution, so if you have same troubles as me:

1) let the NextGenGallery automaticaly resize uploaded images

2) for downloading hi-res image you have two options how to use [NextGEN Download Gallery](http://shop.webaware.com.au/downloads/nextgen-download-gallery/)

1. upload images whenever you want on your site and just change the path by the `addfilter ngg_dlgallery_image_path` - see [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/linking-to-hr-images-again?replies=24#post-4385317) on WP forum for detailed answer
2. or use backup files created by NextGenGALLERY by changing the source code of plugin - see [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/hires-download?replies=2)

or you combine them into addfilter and use _backup image (which is the best I think)